# Lightbox taglines or titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am trying to have a title or tag under each lightbox photo but the second I do that it makes all of the pictures vertical instead of stacked horizontal in one row or collapsible in different browsers. I'll add codepens because the java script is too long for the snippets here. The first one shows the way I want the lightbox to function (that doesn't have the taglines) and then the second one has the tagline that I want, but is stacking the wrong way. If anyone can help me figure out this issue that will be really helpful! Thank you!

First Codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpLjOp

```
<div id="recentwork">
<h2 id="recent"> Most Recent Work</h2>


<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2   /Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
    </a>
```

Second Codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNBpQm

```
<div id="recentwork">
<h2 id="recent"> Most Recent Work</h2>


<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
    </a>
    <h3> Title</h3>


    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
    </a>
    <h3> Title</h3>

<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
        </a>
        <h3> Title</h3>

    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
        </a>
        <h3> Title</h3>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the `h3` within the `a`, and then a user could click on either to follow the link.

```
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" data-lightbox="website" data-title="">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f2/Seesmic_Logo.png" width="200px" height="200px">
    <h3> Title</h3>
</a>
```

To line the images horizontally use:

```
#recentwork a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/jyjVEW?editors=1100)

Comment: Thank you so so much! I thought I had tried that but I must have done it wrong. This worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help! @ovokuro